P-channel MOSFET LED dimmer
I am building the dimmer circuit for the LED array.  The circuit is based on P-channel MOSFET.  The circuit works but I afraid that the MOSFET can be damaged when the potentiometer R1 is in its lowest position (i.e., when the gate of the Q1 is at ground potential).  How can I modify the circuit to make it better/safer for the MOSFET? 

48 V should be very "bad" ... Make a limit with a zener and resistor added or something like.

Well, 48V is required to this LED strip to operate.  I think the problem is not 48V since in order to "open" the p-channel MOSFET, its gate should be at the same potential as the source.  To dim the LEDs, the lower potential is applied to the gate.  The problem could arise when the gate potential is close to the ground.  I need to somehow limit the lower value of the gate potential

Meanwhile I thought to add a 47 resistor between the ground and the lower terminal of the potentiometer R1.  This should limit the lower gate potential to 24V.

What does the datasheet say about the maximum Vgs? And how much would you need to turn it on fully enough for your LEDs?

Continuous gate to source voltage +/- 15V.  I need to apply 48V to turn on the LEDs fully.  The LED array has its own limiting resistor.

Have you considered redesigning the circuit? Put the string of LEDs between the +48V and the source and a resistor between the drain and 0V. Insert  a resistor in series with R1 to limit the voltage on the gate. You've now got a variable constant current drive and you need to do the sums based on the max and min currents you want through the LED.

Well, there you are - 48V is considerably higher than 15V so it's certain to damage the MOSFET. And I meant how much Vgs do you need to turn the MOSFET fully on?

The maximal Vgs is -15V, so I limited it to about -13V by adding a resistor between the lower terminal of the potentiometer and the ground.  The MOSFET seem to be fully on so I think it should be safe now.  Thanks!

Redesigning the circuit to the low-side switch is problematic since I have 3 LED strings with common negative terminals (cathodes), so the switching must be on the high (positive) side to turn these LED strings on independently.
